# Scala parser combinators: how to return the content of intermediate parsers when combined with "into"?

Tags: parsing, scala

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
def parser = parser_a >> {
  case a => val c = compute(a) ; parser_b(c)
} ^^ {
  case a ~ b => (a, b)
}
```

Of course it won't work, since the function after the `^^` operator only gets the result of `parser_b`. How can I keep the result of `parser_a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that parsers are monadic to write this as follows:

```
val parser = for {
  a <- parser_a
  b <- parser_b(compute(a))
} yield (a, b)
```

Alternatively you could change the following line in your solution (note that `success` here is just a less specific version of the general monadic `return`).

```
  case a => val c = compute(a) ; success(a) ~ parser_b(c)
```

I personally find the `for`-comprehension a little clearer in this case, though.